# I get an undefined when trying to read a cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, react-hooks

I have a problem with setting and reading cookies. There is a login mask, a user logs in with an email and password, and if successful, his user ID is saved in a cookie (access_token). If I now call further POST or GETs, it is checked whether the token is still up to date. The problem here is that I get an undefined every time I check. What could be the reason? Thank you very much!

verifyToken.js

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
const token = req.cookies.access_token;

console.log("verifyToken: " + token); //undefined

if (!token) {
return res.status(200).send({
  error: true,
  msg: "Authentication Failed.",
});
}

jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT, (err, user) => {
if (err) {
  return res.status(200).send({
    error: true,
    msg: "Authentication Failed.",
  });
}
 req.user = user;
  next();
 });
};
```

route arts.js

```
import {
 ChangeArt
} from "../controller/arts.js";

import express from "express";
import { verifyToken } from "../verifyToken.js";

const router = express.Router();
router.put("/ChangeArt/:id",verifyToken, ChangeArt);
```

Login.js Frontend

```
 res
    .cookie("access_token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      SameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? false : true,
    })
    .status(200)
    .json(others);
```

Server

```
 //Middleware
const corsOptions = {
 credentials: true,
 origin: "http://localhost:3000", //or production URL
};

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: Are the cookies HttpOnly? If so, you can't read it.

Comment: @testing_22 - This looks like backend code to me so httponly cookies are readable there.

Comment: How are the subsequent requests made where the cookie is not present?  Are they made via Ajax calls?

Comment: @jfriend00 Exactly

Comment: Please show that ajax code then.  If it's `fetch()`, then you may need the option `{ credentials: "include" }` so that it will include cookies.

Comment: I use Axios - I try it directly